# KnockoutJS, Text vs Value Binding. Why Text Binding Doesn't Bind to an Input Field?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

From Knockout tutorial:

Why this works?

```
 <p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
```

While this doesn't?

```
 <p>First name: <input data-bind="text: firstName" /></p>
```

ViewModel

```
// This is a simple *viewmodel* - JavaScript that defines the data and behavior of your UI
 function AppViewModel() {
this.firstName = "Bert";
this.lastName = "Bertington";
}
```

Comment: What does mean `doesn't work` ? Any error ?

Comment: I imagine the same reason The JQuery .text() method cannot be used on form inputs or scripts. To set or get the text value of input or textarea elements, you must use the .val() method. Haven't dug any deeper

Comment: @SnakeEyes, it means, the input field is empty.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because in html, the typed text in an 'input type="text"' is stored in an attribute named value.

The value binding affect the value attribute of the element and the text binding alters the inner text of an element.

By writing

```
<input data-bind="text: firstName" />
```

you are trying to change the content of the input element. And an input doesn't allow a content.

```
<input value="where the value binding writes its data">
    where the text binding writes its data
</input>
```

Comment: Thank you. So basically the input tag doesn't have a text attribute.

Comment: Not "text attribute"; in DOM terms, `<input>` elements can't have any child nodes other than comments and the `text` binding creates child nodes of type `text`, which will be ignored by the browser.